# Jetson Orin onnx-simplifier can't be installed

Tags: yolo, nvidia-jetson

I try to install yolox on jetson orin, i downloaded the yolox files from github and when i try to install the requirements, i get an error at the end which is the onnx-simplifier. I try to install the specified version, but none of the versions are properly installed so yolox won't run on jetson orin.

This is from the error message i get:

INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of yolox to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnx-simplifier==0.4.10 (from yolox) (from versions: 0.0.0, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11, 0.2.12, 0.2.13, 0.2.14, 0.2.15, 0.2.16, 0.2.17, 0.2.18, 0.2.19, 0.2.20, 0.2.21, 0.2.22, 0.2.23, 0.2.24, 0.2.25, 0.2.26, 0.2.27, 0.2.28, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.3.10, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.4.13, 0.4.15, 0.4.17, 0.4.19, 0.4.20, 0.4.21, 0.4.22, 0.4.23, 0.4.24, 0.4.25, 0.4.26, 0.4.27, 0.4.28, 0.4.30, 0.4.31, 0.4.33)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnx-simplifier==0.4.10